# How to change syntax highlighting colors of Avalon edit (WPF)?

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, syntax-highlighting, avalonedit

I'm using the AvalonEdit text editor for a project in WPF and I need to change the syntax colors of a language.

I installed the Nuget package and wrote `xmlns:avalonEdit="http://icsharpcode.net/sharpdevelop/avalonedit"` in the XAML of the MainWindow.

`<avalonEdit:TextEditor Foreground="White" SyntaxHighlighting="PHP" ShowLineNumbers="True" FontSize="16">`

How can I change the colors of a language?
I saw some files in the AvalonEdit Sample demo folder "ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit\Highlighting\Resources", but I dont Know how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the syntax rules but just change the colors it is quite easy. I changed them to match Visual Studio for C# like this (`editor` refers to my `ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.TextEditor`):

```
var highlighting = editor.SyntaxHighlighting;
highlighting.GetNamedColor("StringInterpolation").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Black);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("Punctuation").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Black);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("NumberLiteral").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Black);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("Comment").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.ForestGreen);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("MethodCall").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.DarkGoldenrod);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("GetSetAddRemove").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("Visibility").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("ParameterModifiers").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("Modifiers").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("String").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Brown);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("Char").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Red);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("Preprocessor").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("TrueFalse").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("Keywords").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("ValueTypeKeywords").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("SemanticKeywords").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("NamespaceKeywords").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("ReferenceTypeKeywords").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("ThisOrBaseReference").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("NullOrValueKeywords").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("GotoKeywords").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("ContextKeywords").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("ExceptionKeywords").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("CheckedKeyword").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("UnsafeKeywords").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("OperatorKeywords").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);
highlighting.GetNamedColor("SemanticKeywords").Foreground = new SimpleHighlightingBrush(Colors.Blue);

foreach (var color in highlighting.NamedHighlightingColors) {
    color.FontWeight = null;
}
editor.SyntaxHighlighting = null;
editor.SyntaxHighlighting = highlighting;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change syntax highlighting by loading your own highlighting definition at run time. See this entry for more details: [How do I create an AvalonEdit syntax file (.xshd) and embed it into my assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057210/how-do-i-create-an-avalonedit-syntax-file-xshd-and-embed-it-into-my-assembly)